# Sampling InfluxDB time series data at a specific timestamp with linear interpolation

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I have an InfluxDB2 time series database with samples taken *roughly* every 6 hours, but sometimes additional samples might be in between, or sometimes samples might be missing. I know that the measurement is noise-free and that the underlying measured value is continuous and doesn't change rapidly.

The thing that I'd like to do with this data is to query it at a given point in time, with linear interpolation (and this sounds like one of the most basic operations to me). I do not care whether there is a sample close to it or not, and I don't want to know about explicit samples in a given window. I really only want to treat the data as a piecewise-linear curve, and get the curve's value at a given point in time.

I have looked through the internet, yet haven't found an adequately easy way to do this. Lots of resources seem to use the outdated InfluxQL language, or do some (in my book) overly complicated thing like aggregating windows which I don't think is necessary or even desirable for what I am trying to do.

What's the easiest way to get a linearly-interpolated measurement value at a given timestamp in InfluxDB2? If Influx for some reason is the wrong tool for what I am doing here, I am happy to hear alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to do with this data is to query it at a given point in time, with linear interpolation.

Suppose you are doing the same query every 30 minute. That means, you want to have data at least for every 30 minute, whether the data was inserted by the data source or interpolated by InfluxDB.

You could try following sample code via Flux language to the fill the missing values:

```
import "interpolate"

data
    |> interpolate.linear(every: 30m)
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/interpolate/linear/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I think I could piece something together with this, but it sure isn't an ideal straightforward solution: 1) I can't submit an unbounded read to my bucket, so I need to bound the data first in a way that I am sure that a previous and next sample for my timestamp are included - which, if many samples are missing, isn't straightforward. 2) If my desired timestamp is e.g. 4:37:31.000, I need to interpolate every 1s, which doesn't seem to execute lazily even if I filter it down to only that time afterwards, so it takes a long time. It seems an offset is not possible here :/

Comment: w.r.t your first concern, you could try [InfluxDB v2's Tasks](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/process-data/get-started/) which will run your queries regularly once you set them up. w.r.t your second concern, that Tasks has an [offset option](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/process-data/get-started/#use-offset-to-account-for-latent-data). Hope it could help.